Adjusting the Position of CollectionView Controller
I am creating a simple Application which present a collection view.
in AppDelegate, I use the following code:
    let feedController = FeedController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: feedController)

When I running the application,

the view appear little down as see in below photo.
how can I move the collectionview up to the top of arrow
I am using FeedCell as uiCollectionViewCell for setting up the cell.
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    setupViews()
}

and for setupViews(), it is as below:
func setupViews() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.white
           
    addSubview(nameLabel)
    addSubview(profileImageView)
    addSubview(statusTextView)
    addSubview(statusImageView)

    addConstraintWithFormat(format: "H:|-8-[v0(44)]-8-[v1]|", views: profileImageView,nameLabel)
    addConstraintWithFormat(format: "H:|-4-[v0]-4-|", views: statusTextView)
    addConstraintWithFormat(format: "H:|-8-[v0]-8-|", views: statusImageView)
    addConstraintWithFormat(format: "H:|-12-[v0]|", views: visitAppleStore)        
}


How do the collectionView inside FeedController align with its parent controller?

I edited my question. can you kindly look into it?

UICollectionView is descendant of UIScrollView class which has contentInset property, setting .never inset adjustment probably fixes the problem
collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never


it did not work properly
